# Using a script to control a process already running in screen

Tags: gnu-screen

Due to Gnu Screen being hard to Google for, I've been having trouble finding an answer to this one.

As a concrete (what are you trying to do) example:
Running a server process (under linux) starts up a bunch of output (STDOUT STDERR) which can take input from STDIN.
Periodically I want to issue a command (`/snapshot`) to backup the current state.
I want to setup cron to run a command that occasionally injects this into the STDIN for the server.

So far I've been thinking that the server process could run in a detached screen session. And I think that screen's exec command can connect to different terminal sessions under screen and hand STDIN and STDOUT to another process. But reading the [docs](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/screen/screen_87.html) has been confusing. And it doesn't help that they say there's a "confusing illustration" to explain this further.

If anyone has done this, how do I specify a cron command to accomplish this.
So far I'm thinking (show what you've done):

```
5 * * * * /usr/bin/screen -p 1 -X 'exec ! echo "/snapshot"'
```

But here I don't know if that'll work, if that would actually target the server process in window 1, and what happens after that; does screen exit?

Comment: ./~ Someday my answerer will come ./~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I fully understand your concrete use case, but here's a possible approach which may help.

Rather than have your process dump to `stdout` and `stderr`, have those written to a file. Alternately, you could use `tee` to write to a file and to the terminal.

Also redirect `stdin` using `tail -f` on a separate input file. Create a cron job which writes a new line to the input file at the appropriate interval.

You can still run your process in `screen` if you want to periodically check on it (or just to keep it alive).

Start your process like:

```
tail -f /path/to/myinputfile.txt | myprocess 2&>1 >/path/to/outputfile.txt
```

or, using `tee`:

```
tail -f /path/to/myinputfile.txt | myprocess 2&>1 | tee /path/to/outputfile.txt
```

And set up the input cron job like:

```
5 * * * * /bin/cat "/snapshot" >> /path/to/myinputfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanks; I like this solution. I thought `screen` might support something like this too though; E.G. if I only wanted to send a character or two without a newline the `tail -f` would be an issue.